# Django modelformset with customized model initialization

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform, formset

I have the following models in django:

```
class tag(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(user)
    shop = models.ForeignKey(shop)
    name = models.CharField()
    ...

class user(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.CharField()
    ...

class shop(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(user)
    name = models.CharField()
    ...
```

Now I need to create a modelformset of tag model that will allow me to store bunch of different tags per user. What I am looking for is a way to initialize such formset with a shop field filtered out for a given user.

This way my forms would have a selection of shops that are assigned to the user.

Any ideas are very welcome!
Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want a formset that when given a user each form is a name and shop input where the shop input is filtered? Maybe your models would help.

Comment: You're right. It's kinda difficult for me to explain, so I edited my post. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`inlineformset_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/models/#inlineformset-factory) to create a formset for related models. To create a formset for your `tag` and `user` model you can do the following:

```
tag_formset = inlineformset_factory(user, tag, fields=['shop', 'name'])
formset = tag_formset(instance=request.user)
```

To filter the queryset for the `shop` field you can either create a form dynamically or pass `formfield_callback` to the factory function.

If you use `formfield_callback`, this callback can be used to return a custom field for your form

```
def cb(field, **kwargs):
    if field.name == 'shop':
        kwargs['queryset'] = shop.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return field.formfield(**kwargs)

tag_formset = inlineformset_factory(user, tag, fields=['shop', 'name'], formfield_callback=cb)
formset = tag_formset(instance=request.user)
```

Or you can define a form class dynamically in your view

```
class TagForm(forms.ModelForm):
    shop = forms.ModelChoiceField(shop.objects.filter(user=request.user))
    class Meta:
        fields = ['shop', 'name']

tag_formset = forms.inlineformset_factory(user, tag, form=TagForm)
formset = tag_formset(instance=request.user)
```

Comment: Brilliant! I am still new to django formset and wasn't aware of the inlineformset_factory. Your answer definitely helps. Cheers!